# Microsoft Access - Filtering metadata so that one field is less than a particular value it will exclude an entire set of data

Tags: metadata, filtering

I am trying to filter something like this:

```
Field1     Field2     Field3 

1             1          10   // set 1

1             1          20    // set 1

1             1          10    // set 1

1              2         12    // set 2

1              2         15    // set 2

2              3         10   // set 3

2              3         12   // set 3
```

A set is the entire data set when Field1 and Field2  are constant. There are three sets. I wish to filter the data so that if Field3 is greater than a certain value, then the entire set that is associated with that is eliminated. For example; if that certain value is 19, then the filtered data set would look like:

```
Field1     Field2      Field3 

 1              2         12    // set 2

 1              2         15    // set 2

 2              3         10   // set 3

 2              3         12   // set 3
```

Thus, eliminating set 1 completely because one of it's values (20) in Field3 > 19.

Basically, if one field does not satisfy a particular condition I would like to remove the entire set.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM YourTable LEFT JOIN (SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM YourTable GROUP BY Field1, Field2 HAVING Max(Field3)>19 ) As T ON YourTable.Field1 = T.Field1 AND YourTable.Field2 = T.Field2 WHERE T.Field1 Is Null